# RecyclerView ClickListener

Tags: android-recyclerview

Hello Perhaps for someone this question is considered really easy, but I have been fighting this question for 2 weeks. How is clicking on the TextView so that there is a transition to the site, or at least in which direction to go. Clicking occurs, but the transition to clicking is not and that's it. in recyclerview

I will be glad for any help[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYGY2.jpg)